# angular urls in sitemap.xml with hashbang or not?

Tags: angularjs, sitemap

how should I put Angular url's in the `sitemap.xml`?

Now I've added this:

`https://www.domain.com/user-area#!/logon`

but I think Google doesn't like it.

I've read about the `_escaped_fragment_` but I don't understand what that means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_escaped_fragment_` was recently depreciated by google. See their blog post here: 
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Anyways, from what you wrote, it seems like your server structure isn't prepared for the `_escaped_fragment_`. I won't go into too much detail about it here, since it was depreciated after all.

Anyways, Google's bots weren't always able to process websites with AJAX content (content rendered via Javascript). To create a workaround, Google proposed adding the hashbang `#!` to all AJAX sites. Bots would be able to detect the hashbang and know that the website had content rendered through AJAX. The bots would then request a pre-rendered version of the AJAX pages by replace the hashbang with the `_escaped_fragment_`. However, this required the server hosting the AJAX pages to know about the `_escaped_fragment_` and be able to serve up a pre-rendered page, which was a difficult process to set up and execute.

Now, according to the depreciation blogpost, the URL you entered in your `sitemap.xml` should be fine, since Google's bots should be able to "crawl, render, and index the #! URLs". If you really want to know if Google can understand your website, I'd recommend using their webmaster console, located at https://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/ . Using that tool, you can register your site with google, observe how google indexes your site, and be notified if any problems arise with your site.

In general though, getting Google to index an AJAX site is a pain. I'd strongly recommend using the webmaster console and referring to it frequently. It does help.

Comment: Thanks very much for the thorough explanation!